# Conceptual subspace question.

Tags: linear-algebra

Say you have subspaces $U_2,U_1 \subseteq U_{0}$ what does $U_2+U_0=U_1+U_0$ mean? What if $U_2$ and $U_1$ are lines through the origin, and $U_0$ is a plane in $\mathbb{R^3}$ through the origin. When does $U_1 = U_2$?

To my understanding, if the lines already lie inside both planes, then would it matter what lines were added? In other words, could you take any $U_1,U_2$?

Comment: If $U\subseteq V$, then $U+V=V$.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are talking about the usual sum of vector spaces, then it follows from the definition of sum that $U_2+U_0=U_0$  and $U_1+U_0=U_0$. That is, if you take a subspace of another larger subspace, then the sum is equal to the larger one.

Therefore it wouldn't matter if you take $U_1$ or $U_2$, as long as they are subspaces of the plane.

If, say, $U_1$ is not a line on the plane $U_0$, then the sum of the spaces would be the whole space $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Good answer, thanks. :D

Comment: In the case where $U_1 \nsubseteq U_0$,the reason that we get all of $\mathbb{R^{3}}$, is because  $U_1$ is linearly independent from $U_0$, correct?

Comment: Pretty much, although the use of "linearly independent" is usually reserved for vectors and sets of vectors, and not spaces. With this in mind, we could phrase your observation like this: we can find a vector $\alpha$ in $U_1$ and a basis $\{\beta,\gamma\}$ of $U_2$ such that $\{\alpha,\beta,\gamma\}$ is l.i. (and therefore spans $\mathbb{R}^3$).